# Redux: Derived data for items in a collection

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is a simplified version of my state tree:

```
{
    "radius": 8,
    "nodes": [
        { "id": 1, "x": 10, "y": 10 },
        { "id": 2, "x": 15, "y": 10 },
        { "id": 3, "x": 20, "y": 10 }
    ]
}
```

Essentially, I have a list of nodes that each have an *x* and a *y*. I also have a radius number that is used to calculate which other nodes are within the radius of a node, ie, close neighbors.

I need my state to look like this:

```
{
    "radius": 8,
    "nodes": [
        { "id": 1, "x": 10, "y": 10, "neighbors": [2] },
        { "id": 2, "x": 15, "y": 10, "neighbors": [1, 3] },
        { "id": 3, "x": 20, "y": 10, "neighbors": [2] }
    ]
}
```

The calculation for the neighbors is rather expensive, so I only really want to calculate this if one of the node positions changes.

I looked into used selectors for this, but I'm not sure a selector will work. In order to derive the neighbor of a given node, I need the whole list of nodes and the radius. If I pass the whole list of nodes to the selector, the selector will recalculate if anything in the node collection has changed. I only need to recalculate if the x or y value of any node has changed. Note that these nodes have a lot of other keys, in addition to *x* and *y*.

It also seems that for selectors to work, I would need a new selector for each element of the nodes array, which is dynamic.  Is this correct?

Another hurdle is that I need this list of neighbors to calculate other state in other reducers. Does this mean I should do this calculation in the nodes reducer?

Does anyone have any insight on this problem?

***EDIT**

I ended up moving the neighbors into the state instead of deriving them.  I needed access to the neighbors from within the reducers for certain other actions, and I was not able to find a way to cache/memoize them.

It seems a little fragile, because I'm essentially deriving and storing the neighbors on certain actions that involve them and not re-deriving them on others that don't.  (That's pretty much what a memoized selector would be doing automatically...) But alas, I couldn't find a good way to do that.

Is this wrong?

***EDIT2**
I ended up splitting my nodes state into two parts:

```
nodes: {
    nodesById: {
        "1": { "id": 1, "color": "blue", ... },
        "2": { "id": 2, "color": "red", ... },
        ...
    },
    positionsById: {
        "1": { "id": 1, "x": 0, "y": 10 },
        "2": { "id": 2, "x": 10, "y": 10 },
        ...
    }
}
```

This way, I am able to write a selector that takes just the positions of the nodes and the radius to compute the neighbors:

```
export const getNeighborsById = createSelector(
    (positionsById, radius) => positionsById,
    (positionsById, radius) => radius,
    (positionsById, radius) => {
        // calculate neighbors
    }
);
```

This selector will only be re-run when the `positionsById` changes and not when `nodesById` changes (which happens much more).

This solves my problem, but seems kinda wrong to maintain two lists in the same reducer, but maybe not...

Comment: we're facing the exact same problem. Did you find a usable pattern?

Comment: @AntonAbilov The final solution that I used is described above in EDIT2.  It's essentially normalizing my redux state by breaking the entities apart (node and node position) and storing them each in a dictionary indexed by id.

Answer (score 2):

There are several common misconceptions about states in Redux:

1. *state must be described using native JS types.* **Wrong**
2. *state represents what's shown in the screen.* **Partially wrong**

#### 1. Use the right data structures

According to your use case, storing your nodes into an `Array` does not seem to be the best option. Yes, you could do this but whenever a node is added, removed or modified you would need to walk your list and update `neighbors`. If you move this process to a selector, you would need some kind of memoization not to sacrifice the performance.

In my opinion your nodes should be stored in spatial-partitioning data structure (e.g. an immutable quadtree). This kind of DS would make node traversal much faster and it should not be too hard to identify neighbors.

#### 2. Use selectors to derive your state

A selector is useful when you have to perform a complex selection on your state or if you need to derive your state into another shape before using it.

If your nodes are stored in a quardtree, it would be easy to write a selector to query its neighbors and return them as an array.

Comment: That's a good idea to use a quadtree, I think I'll do that.  But I still need a solution to avoid doing this calculation on every update.  I'm thinking about having a dedicated tree for "nodePosition" and other trees for other  properties of the nodes.

Comment: You can memoize the calculation using `reselect`

Comment: I don't think I can use `reselect` because the calculation is done for each node in the collection.  Reselect will only memoize the last calculation.  That's something I've been struggling with. Do I use another method to memoize more traditionally? or create a new `reselect` selector for every node in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a very similar issue in my app this week and I ended up creating memoized selectors inside of the components that represent each item in my collection. That way I can feed the specific data for each item into the `Reselect.createSelector` in each component rather than trying to make some super selector that handles all of the elements in the collection.